# RCP Application coundn't find new added view

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am using Eclipse Juno for RCP RAP developer. I have created a Plug-in Project with a single view and it runs normally. But whenever I tried to add a new view into that workbench, the window dosent update. Also if I change the id of the current view, it also not working. And if I delete the current view, it also showing it. As a whole, the view part is not updating of the application. Anybody knows any answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your changes doesn't get applied correctly.

> Eclipse 4 persists certain user changes in your application. During
>   development this might lead to situations where changes are not
>   correctly applied and displayed, e.g. you define a new menu entry and
>   this entry is not displayed in your application.

You have to add `-clearPersistedState` as a program argument for your application **or** set the `Clear` flag in the Main tab of your Run configuration.

Take a look [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#tutorial_clearpesistence) for further information and a more detailed description.